# Magento Module Admin Controller Returns 404 Error

Tags: magento

I am creating simple reports module by following this [tutorial](http://codemagento.com/2011/03/creating-custom-magento-reports/).When i try to open

> http://localhost/dev/admin/adminhtml/report_example/simple

i get 404 error.Any help would be appreciated.Here's what i did

app/etc/modules/Package_Custom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Package_Custom>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Package_Custom>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Package/Custom/controllers/Adminhtml/Report/ExampleController.php

```
<?php

class Package_Custom_Adminhtml_Report_ExampleController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function _initAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout()->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('custom')->__('Custom'),Mage::helper('custom')->__('Custom'));
        return $this;
    }
}
?>
```

app/code/local/Package/Custom/etc/adminhtml.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <custom translate="title" module="custom">
            <title>Custom</title>
            <sort_order>15</sort_order>
            <children>
                <simple translate="title" module="custom">
                    <title>Simple Report<</title>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/report_example/simple</action>
                </simple>
            </children>
        </custom>
    </menu>
```

app/code/local/Package/Custom/etc/config.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
        <Package_Custom>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Package_Custom>
    </modules>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <custom before="Mage_Adminhtml">Package_Custom_Adminhtml</custom>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem.In config.xml

```
<title>Simple Report<</title>
```

Should be

```
<title>Simple Report</title>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure acl section in the adminhtml.xml
http://www.ecomdev.org/2010/10/28/defining-acl-resources-custom-and-admin-menu-in-magento.html